# can't remove a pad outside the board in ALtium designer 2016

Tags: pcb-design, altium, layout

i accidently placed a pad in my pcb layout outside the pcb box. but now i cant remove it.

could you suggest a method to remove it?
i use altium designer 2016.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

STEP1: Open the PCB panel.

[image]

STEP2: Select on the opened panel "Hole Size Editor" and select needed PAD.
[image]

STEP3: Double click the mouse to go into the configuration and change the coordinates so that it was in the field of visibility.
[image]

STEP4: Delete!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the grid coarse (like 100 mils/2.5mm), hit Ctrl-A to select everything, then drag it up so the errant pad is visible. Delete it, then Ctrl-A again and drag everything back.